# The type 'System.IO.Stream' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: .net, dll, stream, tumblr, system.io.directory

I get this compile time error when creating a FileStream for reading an image for use with the [TumblrSharp](https://tumblrsharp.codeplex.com/) library.

I have tried adding the reference through Add Reference but there is no System.IO reference to be added. I also tried browsing manually to the .NET 4.0 framework folder and selecting the DLL that way but it isn't there. My application shows a using statement of System.IO without any errors underlined in the file.

```
The type 'System.IO.Stream' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.IO, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I also made sure my project targeted .NET 4.5 to match what the TumblrSharp PCL targets. Here is the code:

```
static async void PostImages()
{
    var factory = new TumblrClientFactory();

    using (var client = factory.Create<TumblrClient>(consumerKey, consumerSecret, new Token(ConsumerToken, ConsumerSecret)))
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(imageFolder);
        var files = directory.EnumerateFiles();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var image = file.OpenRead();
            var bytes = new byte[image.Length];
            image.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(image.Length));

            var tags = file.Name.Split('$')[1].Split(',');

            var post = PostData.CreatePhoto(new[] { new BinaryFile(bytes) }, null, "http://www.example.com");
            post.Tags.AddRange(tags);

            var result = await client.CreatePostAsync("blogname", post);

            if (result.PostId <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            file.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reinstall the framework?

Comment: Try targetting 4.0 not 4.5

Comment: You must describe the kind of project you have created.  Doesn't look like a Store or Phone app, you'd get a *lot* more errors.  If it is a PCL Library project then you must tell us about the targets you selected.

Comment: It's just a console application targeting 4.5.1

Answer (score 2):

For a PCL, I had to manually add references to the compilation section of web.config for the required assemblies, e.g.:

```
<add assembly="System.IO, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue. Read this article:
[Error message when you compile applications to target the .NET Framework 4.5.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005)

You should install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack